# c++ implicit entry/start for main executable error

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a problem in running Hadoop pipes code on Mac.
This is my c++ code.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>

#include "Pipes.hh"
#include "TemplateFactory.hh"
#include "StringUtils.hh"
using namespace std;

class MaxTemperatureMapper : public HadoopPipes::Mapper {
public:
  MaxTemperatureMapper(HadoopPipes::TaskContext& context) {
  }
  void map(HadoopPipes::MapContext& context) {
    std::string line = context.getInputValue();
    std::string year = line.substr(15, 4);
    std::string airTemperature = line.substr(87, 5);
    std::string q = line.substr(92, 1);
    if (airTemperature != "+9999" &&
        (q == "0" || q == "1" || q == "4" || q == "5" || q == "9")) {
      context.emit(year, airTemperature);
    }
  }
};

class MapTemperatureReducer : public HadoopPipes::Reducer {
public:
  MapTemperatureReducer(HadoopPipes::TaskContext& context) {
  }
  void reduce(HadoopPipes::ReduceContext& context) {
    int maxValue = INT_MIN;
    while (context.nextValue()) {
      maxValue = std::max(maxValue, HadoopUtils::toInt(context.getInputValue()));
    }
    context.emit(context.getInputKey(), HadoopUtils::toString(maxValue));
  }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    int i=HadoopPipes::runTask(HadoopPipes::TemplateFactory<WordCountMap, WordCountReduce>()); // 运行任务
    return 0;
}
```

My makefile is:

```
wordcount :wordcount.cpp
    g++ -Wall -I/Users/macbookpro/Documents/hadoop-2.7.5/include -L/Users/macbookpro/Documents/hadoop-2.7.5/lib/native -lhadooppipes -lhadooputils -lpthread -lcrypto -lssl -g -O2 -o $@
```

When I tried to compile the source file, I got an error saying that

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_main", referenced from:
>        implicit entry/start for main executable ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: *** [wordcount] Error 1

I don't know what this means because I already have a main function.

could you solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you just compile it directly without using makefile?

Comment: if I just compile it using "g++ word count.cpp",there'll be another error:wordcount.cc:6:10: fatal error: 'hadoop/Pipes.hh' file not found
#include "hadoop/Pipes.hh"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass the source file to the recipe, the easiest way to avoid this here is to just rely on the built-in make rule for one-shotting programs, all you need is:

```
CPPFLAGS := -I/Users/macbookpro/Documents/hadoop-2.7.5/include -pthread
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -g -O2
LDFLAGS  := -L/Users/macbookpro/Documents/hadoop-2.7.5/lib/native -pthread 
LDLIBS   := -lhadooppipes -lhadooputils -lcrypto -lssl

wordcount:
```

The make implicit rule for `%: %.cpp` will take care of the rest. Note that you're using `pthread` incorrectly, you need to pass the `pthread` option to the preprocessor and linker, not the lib.